# Cannot Change the Version of R in RStudio

Tags: r, version, rstudio

My RStudio (V 0.99.491) is inept to change the R Version.
I act in the ordinary way through `Global Options --> R-Version`. Afterwards it hangs and doesn't work or react any more. The initial version of R which works fine is `R 3.1.0`. I have never had such a problem before. Maybe someone has faced with a similar problem.

I tried to uninstall RStudio, and install it again, but this hasn't help to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried installing a current version of R from CRAN?

Comment: Certainly. I did! RStudio is inept to change to any other version independet is it an upper or lower one.

Comment: On a Mac, any way, you can have the most recent version of R running. Maybe you just need to reinstall  RStudio. I'm at Version 0.99.491 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had the same problem. Using my user account RStudio hangs up trying to change the version. All other accounts work fine.

I have located the problem in the folder C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\ and renamed this folder. After this everything worked fine.

I assume the problem was the file "desktop.ini.lock", because in the new folder RStudio generated, this file is missing.

Comment: Did you create the path C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\ and drag&drop the RStudio to the new location? Sorry, I did not really get how you settle the problem. user6034358

Comment: The path C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\ is generated automatically from my RStudio. And sometimes (I don't know when and why) the "desktop.ini.lock" file is created in this folder. Deleting this file worked for me. I am using RStudio on Windows, maybe the path to the file is different on your system and maybe it's a hidden folder. Reinstalling R or RStudio does not help, because the personal User-Files are not deleted.

Comment: In Fact, it solved the problem! I have no idea, what is the `desktop.ini.lock` but deleting it fixed the long-lasted problem. Thanks a lot! Additionally, AppData was a hidden folder.