# RStudio - Change R version doesn't works

Tags: r, rstudio, microsoft-r

I have installed two version of R (Base-R and Microsoft R). Actually the Microsoft R version is Default and now I want to change to Base-R. In RStudio -> Options it is pretty simple to change the version. But when I select the Base-R version I get the following message:

"You need to quit and re-open RStudio in order for this change to take effect"

And then I press I "OK" and RStudio stops working. I try this multiple times. Why this doesn't works?

Is the a command to change the version to Base-R? Because I don't want to deinstall Microsoft R.

Thanks!

Comment: Please send bug reports to the RStudio support. Having said that: Are you sure that your RStudio version supports both R versions? Have you updated everything?

Comment: I'm sure that RStudio supports both versions. And I have updated nothing.

Comment: When I say "versions" I don't mean base R vs MS R. I'm referring to version numbers (which you should provide in your bug report to RStudio).

Comment: Where can I find this bug Report? And is there no command to change the version?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for R Studio, for Windows, R Studio determines the version using the system registry, if when you installed MRS and inserted those registry entries, this may be causing a conflict. Try re-adding the registry keys for Open Source R as found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f):

```
When you run the R installer, there are options (under ‘Select Additional 
Tasks’) to ‘Save version number in registry’ and (for Administrator 
installs) ‘Associate R with .RData files’.

If you tick the first option, the following string entries are added to the 
Windows registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\Current Version contains the version 
number, currently 3.4.0.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\R-core\R\[version]\InstallPath (where [version] 
is currently 3.4.0) contains the path to the R home directory.
If you do not have administrative privileges on the machine while running 
the installer, then the entries are created under HKEY_CURRENT_USER. The 
same entries are also created under Software\R-core\R32 or Software\R-
core\R64, for 32- and 64-bit R respectively.

If you tick the second option (shown with administrative privileges only) 
(‘Associate R with .RData files’) then entries are created under 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.RData and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RWorkspace.

After installation you can add the Registry entries by running RSetReg.exe 
in a sub-folder of the bin folder, and remove them by running this with 
argument /U. Note that this requires administrative privileges unless run 
with argument /Personal and neither sets up nor removes the file 
associations.
```

It appers that the standard way to report a bug in RStudio is to make a post in their support community page from [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us) with the subject "Bug Report"

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer should solve your issue:

[Cannot Change the Version of R in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275672/cannot-change-the-version-of-r-in-rstudio)

go to C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\RStudio and delete "desktop.ini.lock" file. 
Or rename folder